# Interactive Login with Azure SDKs from w/in VSCode DevContainer

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, vscode-remote

When using devcontainers on a project where we are relying on MSIs for app-to-app communication, we are utilizing `DefaultAzureCredential` as the class to load either from the local developer's machine or, on Azure, the MSI of the running service. In order to get this working, I found we needed to add the `includeInteractiveCredentials: true` parameter to the constructor. This results in an actual browser window getting popped from when the code is hit (pretty cool, honestly). If we didn't have this parameter set, it wasn't picking up any user creds to access the resources.

The problem we're having is when we load our solution **in its devcontainer**, the browser login that would normally pop at debug time to pull the local user's credentials isn't allowed to start up. Instead we are met with the following error:

> `Azure.Identity: DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed. InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed. Microsoft.Identity.Client: Unable to open a web page using xdg-open. See inner exception for details. Possible causes for this error are: xdg-open is not installed or it cannot find a way to open an url - make sure you can open a web page by invoking from a terminal: xdg-open https://www.bing.com . System.Diagnostics.Process: No such file or directory.`

We then added `xdg-utils` to our `apt-get` call in our Dockerfile but now we are met with

```
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/...'
```

I've gone so far as clicking the link/pasting it in to my host OS browser, logging in, then looking at the port that's attempted for callback (e.g. `localhost:44663`) and immediately doing a "forward port" from the VSCode command pallet but this also failed saying the state object doesn't match.

Additionally, doing an `az login` w/in the container doesn't alleviate the issue.

How are we supposed to use local Azure credentials from within a Dev Container? Keep in mind we'd like to avoid having to create a Service Principal *in Azure* just to get *local* development working.

Comment: For those wondering, the error we get without setting interactive=true is `An exception of type 'Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.'`

Comment: have your team considered to supporting [authorization-code-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code)?

Comment: We have but that's far too much plumbing in the code to enable the local dev experience. Fortunately, the newer Identity SDKs seem as though they'll solve this problem